# Bookmark without pop-up prompt in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, bookmarks, vimperator

I usually bookmark pages pressing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> but it pops up a prompt asking for confirmation or additional editing including assigning tags.

I used to to bookmark with <kbd>A</kbd> key of [vimperator](/questions/tagged/vimperator), but Vimperator messes up with a lot of other things so I disable it for now.

Is there a plugin or configuration trick (in `about:config` or `user.js` configuration files) to disable such an annoying prompt to make it quite and uninteractive (esp. when bookmarking is done a lot)?

Comment: This addon could work: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/versions/  (from the description: Add a bookmark without showing the Bookmark Dialog.). I haven't tried it, though

Answer (score 2):

The bookmark dialog can now be disabled easily in Firefox 63.

[Bookmarks in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-firefox) on Firefox Help has noted this feature:

> If you don't want to see this editor when saving a bookmark, remove the checkmark from *Show editor when saving*.

That is faster and easier to do than the hidden configuration.

For hidden configuration, open `about:config` in Firefox and look for `browser.bookmarks.editDialog.showForNewBookmarks` with boolean type. Toggle the value to `false` for similar effect.

In terms of documentation, Firefox 63 [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/63.0/releasenotes/) and [developer notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/63) do not seem to mention anything about this "trivial" feature. The only impromptu documentation was found in one of the screenshots used in [the help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-firefox).

> [image: Media preview and information for screenshot]
>
> Source: **Image Info** for **Edit This Bookmark** dialog box, dated 2018-11-16, with associated text "edit bookmark 63".